# Finding median of a set of circular data

Tags: algorithms, median

How to find the median of a set of circular data?e question was first posted at think link:[Finding median of a set of circular data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451427/finding-median-of-a-set-of-circular-data)

As per the suggestions received, I am repeating the question here.

Comment: I see no unique and principled method for defining the median of data over a periodic support.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55615/median-of-points-on-a-circle

Answer (score 0):

Googling indicates that there is a reasonably-well accepted definition of "circular median" exists - see e. g. http://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1738&context=jmasm .  If you put your observations on a circle, the circular median is a point $P$ on that circle such that:

1. the number of observations on each side of the diameter through that point is equal
2. there are more points closer to $P$ than its antipode $Q$.

I am not knowledgeable enough to know a good algorithm for finding the circular median but this is a place to start.